# Python Poetry: How to add a label in version?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I usually have multiple feature branches and share those features with our users for their testing. Then, when satisfied we merge to develop branch. Usually, we do somthing like `0.1.1a0+date` or `0.1.1a0+jiraTaskNumber` or `0.1.1a0+gitBranchName` manually.

I would like to automate this and I am not able to see how to achieve this in poetry because it supports only `poetry version prepatch|major|so_on`.

Can someone help me with how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`poetry version` also takes any valid version number to set the version directly. So you can do:

```bash
poetry version 0.1.1a0+gitBranchName
```

If you want to combine bumping to the next minor, major etc. and a label you can do it like this, from Poetry 1.2 on:

```bash
poetry version "$(poetry version major --dry-run -s)+local"
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting `too many arguments to "version" command` when I run `C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts\poetry version $(C:\Users\selva\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts\poetry version major --dry-run -s)+local --dry-run`

Comment: I do have Poetry 1.2

Comment: Nevermind. I was able to fix this by adding double quotes. `poetry version "$(poetry version major --dry-run -s)+local"`. Thanks a lot for your help. Could you please adjust the answer and then, I can mark it as answered